# Почему кофе - он?

Tags: этимология

Откуда пошла традиция употреблять слово "кофе"  в мужском роде?

Comment: Сначала был кофей. Форма изменилась, род остался.

Comment: 1+ Я согласна с Лораной

Comment: Филей - м.р., филе - ср.р. (?) 

Comment: @grumant 
Это не должно смущать. Все аналогии справеливы до какого-то предела. Здесь одно не может быть образцом для другого, поскольку предлагается "разовое" объяснение под конкреное слово кофе. С филе - другая итория. Там м значение несколько разное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Русский язык претерпел немалые изменения, видоизменились и многие слова, в том числе и слово «кофий» стало произноситься и писаться как «кофе». Все это и стало причиной возникновения вопросов относительно того, к какому роду слово «кофе» относится. Правила русского языка относили «кофе» к словам мужского рода. Тем не менее многие, в том числе и образованные люди, писатели и ученые, нередко употребляли слово в среднем роде.
Сегодня, после внесения соответствующих поправок, слово «кофе» допускается употреблять и в мужском, и среднем роде. Иными словами, можно говорить и «черный кофе», и «черное кофе».
Также нормой для большинства россиян по-прежнему считается употребление слова «кофе» с прилагательными «ароматный», «вкусный», «крепкий».